# $\epsilon -\delta $ criteria for piecewise defined function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let's assume we have the following function
$$f(x):=\begin{cases} 
      h(x) & x<a \\
      i(x) & x=a \\
      j(x) & x>a 
   \end{cases}
$$
and we want to show it is continuous. 
How would we use the criteria?
Thanks in advance. I am only interested in the approach, as the definition says ... $|f(x)-f(a)|< \varepsilon $

Comment: hope this question is not dumb

Comment: It is not dumb.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$, that
$$|h(x)-i(a)|<\varepsilon,\ \text{ for }a-\delta<x<a $$
$$|j(x)-i(a)|<\varepsilon, \ \text{ for }a<x<a+\delta $$
Hard to say anything else.

Further explanation.
$$f\ \text{ is continuous at }a\iff \forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}\forall_{x\in (a-\delta, \ a+\delta)} \left| f(x)-f(a)\right| <\varepsilon \iff \\ \forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}\left(\forall_{x\in (a-\delta, \ a)} \left| f(x)-f(a)\right| <\varepsilon \ \land \forall_{x\in (a, \ a+\delta)} \left| f(x)-f(a)\right| <\varepsilon \ \land \left| f(a)-f(a)\right| <\varepsilon \right ) \\ \iff \forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists_{\delta>0}\left(\forall_{x\in (a-\delta, \ a)} \left| h(x)-i(a)\right| <\varepsilon \ \land \forall_{x\in (a, \ a+\delta)} \left| j(x)-i(a)\right| <\varepsilon  \right )  $$
It's all just matter of dividing the last quantifier in parts.

Comment: you should also notice that for the $x\neq a$, the continuity of $f$ is determined only by the continuity of $h$ or $j$

Comment: @dcolazin I assumed that it's about continuity at $a$

Comment: would choose the same approach. But i miss somehow the WHY. Why would we do this, could you explain that ?

Answer (score 0):

To show it is continuous, we do the following.

For  $x<a$, it is continuous whenever the function $h$ is

For $x=a$, we have to be able to bound $|h(x)-i(a)| < \epsilon$ whenever $x <a$ and $|x-a| < \delta$. This is the same as asking that $\lim_{x\to a} h(x) = i(a)$

We also have to ask the same when we approach from the right.

whenever $x>a$ and $|x-a|<\delta$ we must have $|j(x)-i(a)|<\epsilon$, which is the same as $\lim_{x \to a} j(x) = i(a)$

For $x>a$, $f$ is continuous whenever $j$ is

Comment: where and when do you have to use j(x)

Comment: whenever $x>a$ and $|x-a|<\delta$ we must have $|j(x)-i(a)|<\epsilon$, which is the same as $\lim_{x \to a} j(x) = i(a)$

For $x>a$, $f$ is continuous whenever $j$ is

Comment: so i have to be looking at 2 cases. but why do i take a look at the function h(x) or j(x) because of the definition ?

Comment: because of the definition. Were going to have $|x-a|<\delta$ and that can include $x$ on both sides of $a£

Comment: but the definition says f(x) and im looking at h(x)/j(x) that is the part which i do not fully understand

Comment: But $f(x)$ will turn into the $h(x)$ when $x<a$ so it becomes clear that we must study $h(x)$.

To give you an illustrative example. We might ask why is the function $f(x) = |x|$ continuous at zero. The answer is because if you draw the line $y=-x$ and keep your pen on the paper then draw $y=x$ you don't have to take your hand off the page. It is more or less the same idea but more abstractly

Comment: ahhh now it makes sense thank you for the explanation. mr dewhirst do you a mail, i can contact you on ?

Comment: Yeah sure its gdewhirst22@gmail.com, I take fan mail

Comment: thank you very much, i wont hesitate to contact you if i have questions left. are also good at logical operators and qunators and how to read them correctly such for all x for all y there exisits delta>0 ...

Answer (score 0):

Show that

$$\lim_{x\to a^-}h(x)=i(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}j(x)$$

using the $\delta-\epsilon$ formalism.

Comment: Caution: do not use $\lim_{x\to a}i(x)$.